# How to create a JSF converter for XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: jsf, soap, jsf-2, richfaces

I have created a client for my SOAP web service using JSF and RichFaces. Below is my view:

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid id="panel" width="80%" columns="2" columnClasses="col1,col2">
        <rich:panel>
            <h:outputLabel value="Application Name  " />
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{userComplaintBean.appName}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Select" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="App1" itemLabel="App1" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="App2" itemLabel="App2" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="App3" itemLabel="App3" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="App4" itemLabel="App4" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="App5" itemLabel="App5" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <br />
            <h:outputLabel value="Complaint Description " />
            <h:inputTextarea value="#{userComplaintBean.complaintDesc}" />
            <br />
            <h:outputLabel value="Date Expected  "/>
            <rich:calendar datePattern="yyyy/MM/dd" />
            <br/>
            <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{userComplaintBean.save()}" />
        </rich:panel>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Below is my managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userComplaintBean")
@RequestScoped
public class UserComplaintBean {
    UserComplaintVO userComplaintVO;
    UserComplaintWS userComplaintWS;
    UserComplaintWSImplService userComplaintWSImplService;

    private int id;
    private String appName;
    private String complaintDate;
    private String complaintDesc;
    private Date tentativeDate;

    public XMLGregorianCalendar getComplaintDate() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
        XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = null;
        GregorianCalendar gc;
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        complaintDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        gc = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        gc.setTime(date);
        xgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
        return xgc;
    }

    public void setComplaintDate(String complaintDate) {
        this.complaintDate = complaintDate;
    }

    /*
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getTentativeDate() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
        XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = null;
        GregorianCalendar gc;
        String td;
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");        
        td = dateFormat.format(tentativeDate);
        gc = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        gc.setTime(tentativeDate);
        xgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
        return xgc;
    }

    public void setTentativeDate(Date tentativeDate) {
        this.tentativeDate = tentativeDate;
    }
    */

    public String save() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
        userComplaintWSImplService = new UserComplaintWSImplService();
        userComplaintWS = userComplaintWSImplService.getUserComplaintWSImplPort();
        UserComplaintVO userComplaintVO = new UserComplaintVO();
        userComplaintVO.setAppName(getAppName());
        userComplaintVO.setComplaintDate(getComplaintDate());
        userComplaintVO.setComplaintDesc(getComplaintDesc());
        //userComplaintVO.setTentativeDate(getTentativeDate());
        userComplaintWS.userComplaintMethod(userComplaintVO);
        System.out.println("Complaint Saved...");
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

Here I am taking `complaintDate` from `<rich:calendar>` which I need to convert to `XMLGregorianCalendar` format and I am not able to do it.

How can I do the abovementioned conversion?

Comment: My data is being saved into mysql databse using hibernate and now i want to read the saved data into another .xhtml page .. Im not getting how to do it. Please take this also in consideration

Answer (score 5):

You're basically making a major design mistake. You shouldn't be mingling a SOAP-specific model into your JSF-specific model. The `<rich:calendar>` takes a `java.util.Date`. You should design your model in such way that you provide exactly what the view expects. You should do the SOAP-specific model conversion only afterwards, in the business service method during processing the JSF form submit as preparation for the SOAP request.

Thus, ideally you should be using:

```
private Date copmlaintDate; // +getter+setter
```

with

```
<rich:calendar value="#{userComplaintBean.complaintDate}" />
```

and then in `save()` method

```
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
gc.setTime(complaintDate);
XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
```

---

But if you have really a hard head in for some reason, then you could always hack it around as follows, given that your environment supports EL 2.2 (your action method syntax confirms that this is the case):

```
private XMLGregorianCalendar copmlaintDate; // +getter (no setter necessary!)
```

with

```
<rich:calendar value="#{userComplaintBean.complaintDate.toGregorianCalendar().time}" />
```

---

Otherwise, you could always add a new getter, returning the concrete `java.util.Calendar` instance:

```
public Calendar getComplaintDateAsCalendar() {
    return complaintDate.toGregorianCalendar();
}
```

with

```
<rich:calendar value="#{userComplaintBean.complaintDateAsCalendar.time}" />
```

Comment: BalusC, is the converter approach inappropriate under these circumstances due to poor design considerations?

Comment: @skuntsel: The right type is in this case already accessible as a nested property.

Comment: @BalusC I tried your solution but im getting error ... javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml: Error reading 'complaintBean' on type com.usercomp.bean.userComplaintBean
Also i have kept my soap service from my client .. but my SOAP service needs complaintDate in form of XMLGregorianCalendar thats why i need to do the conversion

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't fully understand the reason behind using an `XMLGregorianCalendar` for keeping the date instances instead of the good old `java.util.Date`, the way to go is to create your own `@FacesConverter` that will do the desired transformation for you. Also, beware of doing business logic / performing potentially lengthy calculations in the getter methods that you're doing righ now. One of the ways of achieving that is to extend the JSF-builtin `DateTimeConverter`.

The kickoff `Converter` example is provided next:

```
@FacesConverter("XMLGregorianCalendarConverter")
public class XMLGregorianCalendarConverter extends DateTimeConverter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if(value == null || value.equals("")) {
            return null;
        }
        Date date = super.getAsObject(context, component, value);
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        cg.setTime(date);
        XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
        if(xgc == null) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Error converting to XMLGregorianCalendar."));
        }
        return xgc;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (!(value instanceof XMLGregorianCalendar) || (value == null)) {
            return null;
        }
        Date date = ((XMLGregorianCalendar)value).toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
        return super.getAsString(context, component, date);
    }

}
```